# How transfer a page type with a form control in it from kentico 10 to Xperience Core

Tags: kentico

I have a Page Type which contains a Form control which was built on Kentico 10.
I need to replicate it on Xperience Asp.Net Core.
Is it possible to create form controls in this environment.

If not, How I can reproduce a Page type with a field who used a form control in the previous version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this documentation here: https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/extending-the-administration-interface/developing-form-controls ?